# Git in Eclipse not recognizing new files

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I'm using built in Git for team projects in Eclipse.

Since yesterday when I'm adding new elements to my project in Eclipse the files are not recognized as synchronized with git and not added to commits.

[image]

I already try to reinstalled Eclipse, updated Git for Windows to last version and re cloned my Git repository.

Any clue what I could try next?

Comment: Did you try doing `git add .` on your project directory?

Comment: yes without result

Comment: do "Team > Share > Git", then check "Use or create repository in parent folder of project". Also, you need to make sure that your git repositories are showing up in the Eclipse Git Repositories view.

Comment: If a _Refresh_ in the _Git Repositories_ view does not solve the problem, look in the `.gitignore` files in parent folders for a pattern that matches the excluded files.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I had a git ignore in the git view which what not displayed in the Java view with the root folder.